# "Flattening" a rectangular image photographed at an angle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, posters

I have photographs of rectangular images that I would like to "flatten" so that they are truly rectangular, rather than the distorted view that comes from a photograph. I know this is something I should be able to Google, but I can't think of a technical term to describe what I mean (it's the process that scanner apps routinely do, essentially "flattening" the photograph).

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tool (perhaps within Illustrator or Photoshop) that will easily take an angled  photograph of a rectangular poster and distort it to become a true rectangle again, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know Illustrator, but in Photoshop you would use the Perspective Crop Tool

[image]

Drag a rectangle from one corner to the opposite, then grab the other corners & move into place.

<sup>Ignore the quality of the shot, very high iso in dimly lit room & I don't have anything you could describe as a 'poster' on my walls ;)</sup>

[image]

Which gives you…

[image]

Comment: I always forget about the perspective crop, it really is exceptionally useful!

Comment: @Alith7 - As I seem to spend an inordinate amount of time on SE squaring up other people's phone snaps of their on-screen computer errors, I do get to use it quite a lot ;)

Comment: I can see that! LOL